# TextView not drawn in Gallery Sometimes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am using an Android Gallery widget to show a series of Layouts, and I am getting some unusual rendering of the TextViews within it. Sometimes the TextViews are drawn so they appear dimmed or maybe part transparent.

This is android 2.2

Here is what the app does, with some screen shots:
1. User drags and drops onto the Gallery to set change the content. This changes the content of the Gallery View, but setting parts of the layout to visible or Gone.

2. The screen updates to this. Look carefully and you will see some text above the green buttons that is not rendering correctly.

3.Finally, user drags away from the Gallery and then back. Voila, the text is rendered as expected. Why does it not work in step 2?

And as a final clue, the text also disappears when the user presses to drag the gallery.
See screenshot below. (listed in order Step 1, Step 2, Step 3)

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

[image: Step 3]

Comment: I think I may have found a solution. I did not set the android:textColor property in the layout. Now that I have set it, the bug seems to be gone. But i will still award an accepted to anyone who can explain why that happened.

Comment: The default color is black and when it gets overlayed ontop of your image I think it is resulting in that color. And if I might say, which is completely off topic, that is one Good looking UI!

Comment: @Ravi - I'm not sure that explains it to me - because in neither case is the text black. in fact, even in the layout preview tool it is grey. But you might be on the right track. 
(also thanks about the UI - I'll tell the designer)

Comment: Thx Plastic Sturgeon... Your fix helped me solve this mystery as well. The bug is stil there of course, but this apparently is a way to work around it. Pretty disturbing it works like this on one version of Android and some other way on another Android version. This sometimes drives me crazy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

I did not set the android:textColor property in the layout.